# svg animate not working in ie

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, svg-animate

I can't get this animation working in ie:

https://jsfiddle.net/p3vnqsy9/

```
<div style="background: red">
    <svg style="padding: 10%" width="80%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                            viewBox="0 0 960 960" enable-background="new 0 0 960 960" id="design-shapes">                               
                            <path fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="40" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round"
                            d="M 0,480 C 0,750, 210,960 480,960 C 750,960, 960,750 960,480 C 960,210 750,0 480,0 C 210,0 0,210 0,480">
                                <animate dur="9000ms" repeatCount="indefinite" attributeType = "XML"
                                attributeName="d"
                                    values="M 0,480 C 0,750, 210,960 480,960 C 750,960, 960,750 960,480 C 960,210 750,0 480,0 C 210,0 0,210 0,480;
                                    M 0,480 C 0,750, 210,960 480,960 C 750,960, 960,750 960,480 C 960,210 750,0 480,0 C 210,0 0,210 0,480;
                                    M 0,480 C 0,750, 210,960 480,960 C 750,960, 960,750 960,480 C 960,210 750,0 480,0 C 210,0 0,210 0,480;
                                    M 480,0 C 480,0 0,840 0,840 C 0,840 480,840 480,840 C 480,840 960,840 960,840 C 960,840 480,0 480,0;
                                    M 480,0 C 480,0 0,840 0,840 C 0,840 480,840 480,840 C 480,840 960,840 960,840 C 960,840 480,0 480,0;
                                    M 480,0 C 480,0 0,840 0,840 C 0,840 480,840 480,840 C 480,840 960,840 960,840 C 960,840 480,0 480,0;
                                    M 0,0, C 0,0 0,960 0,960 C 0,960 960,960 960,960 C 960,960 960,0 960,0 C 960,0 0,0 0,0;
                                    M 0,0, C 0,0 0,960 0,960 C 0,960 960,960 960,960 C 960,960 960,0 960,0 C 960,0 0,0 0,0;
                                    M 0,0, C 0,0 0,960 0,960 C 0,960 960,960 960,960 C 960,960 960,0 960,0 C 960,0 0,0 0,0;
                                    M 0,480 C 0,750, 210,960 480,960 C 750,960, 960,750 960,480 C 960,210 750,0 480,0 C 210,0 0,210 0,480" /></path>
        </svg>
</div>
```

It is working fine elsewhere, am I missing some information?

EDIT

Have updated the jsfiddle to include the fakesmile resource but it still won't work:

https://jsfiddle.net/p3vnqsy9/2/

EDIT 2

Have updated the jsfiddle with correct syntax to allow the animation to work in Firefox:

https://jsfiddle.net/p3vnqsy9/3/

EDIT 3

I cannot get fakesmil to work in IE so have instead opted for the svg-morpheus library. If anyone knows of another solution please let me know...

Answer (score 1):

IE [does not support SMIL](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-smil) natively. There is a [polyfill](https://leunen.me/fakesmile/) for it though called fakesmile.

For what it's worth, the paths are invalid in the animate. commas are only allowed to separate numbers so `M 0,0, C` is invalid from the comma between the 0 and the C. This prevents the animation from working in Firefox.

Comment: I am linking to the fake smile resource in the new jsfiddle but still having no luck:

https://jsfiddle.net/p3vnqsy9/2/

Comment: Perhaps it's because of the syntax error in the values attribute, that certainly breaks it on Firefox.

Comment: Oh, can you elaborate? This animate element is set up to move the individual points, is this a bit of a hack or a legitimate method?

Comment: I did elaborate in my updated answer. Is that unclear in some way?

Comment: Oh christ sorry I didn't see the update only the comment, ta!

Comment: Yes that has fixed the animation in Firefox thanks for spotting that, however the problem with ie still remains